# QProcess::finished ( int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus ) :possible values of exitcode?

Tags: qt, qprocess

I  am  using QProcess to execute shell commands.

How can I determine that command is executed successfully ?

ExitStatus tells that process exited normally or crashed.

What are the possible values of exitcode ?
I am getting variant exitcode for different process.

Answer (score 4):

Any exit code which fits into `int` is possible.

By convention, an exit code of 0 means "success" and anything else means "failure".  This works for all operating systems I know, and there are additional conventions to give more details about errors in some cases.  There is an overview at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status

In practice you will find that almost all programs with a Unix heritage will correctly follow the convention of 0 for success, but some Windows programs will not.  Due to the design differences between the two OS, exit codes tend to be used less correctly on Windows than on Unix.